# Tortoise CVS version 1.12.5 cvs [server aborted]: cannot create CVS/Entries.Extra.Old for copying: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, cvs, permission-denied, tortoisecvs

cvs [server aborted]: cannot create CVS/Entries.Extra.Old for copying: Permission denied

This message appears when doing an update.  However, trying to do another update might succeed.  So, it's possible to make CVS update, but it may take multiple tries, which is annoying.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Why no answer for this? It looks like this error occurs when another program has recently accessed the folders and is still running. In my case it was Beyond Compare and as soon as I closed it, the CVS worked correctly.